# C# winforms webbrowser control, scroll with up and down keys

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a webbrowser control that is inside a tabControl on a windows forms application. I am having a real hard time figuring out how to make it scroll by using arrow keys, as a normal browser does. It works if I press and hold Ctrl while using up and down keys, but aren't there some way to make it work without?

I thought about globally catching the arrow keys, which would be kind of a hack - but then I am left with the problem of programmatically doing a scroll on the webbrowser, which as far as I can see, it does not come with as standard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
private void webBrowser1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down || e.KeyCode == Keys.Up || e.KeyCode == Keys.Left || e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
    {
        e.IsInputKey = true;
        return;
    }

}
```

You might have to change the initial focus. E.g.: is the page is google.com, the focus will be in the Search textbox, so you'll have to play with that a little.

Comment: Absolutely beautiful! Thank you very much. It works just the way I wanted!

Comment: Thank you, I can confirm it works on Windows 10, with Visual Studio 2015 and .NET Framework 2.0 as target.